# SQL Event Rows to Columns timestamp

Tags: sql

First post! I'm a SQL newbie and am trying to query a huge data set into something manageable.

Data below is a for a Dr. office. I have the appointment ID (don't care about the patient name for this), which can have a few different associated events. I want to show all of those events as timestamps by column, with take the most-recent one if there are multiples (the patient rescheduled).

From there, I'll datediff to get the different breakdowns, but I'm not sure how to get there. I've been searching and must be using the wrong terms, so if this has been answered elsewhere, please link me and don't use your time to explain.

[image: What I have and want]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please don't post data as an image. What queries have you tried and what were the results? When asking a question it helps to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where possible. One way you can do this for SQL-related questions is to use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). Also it's important to tag your DBMS when asking SQL-related questions since they're not all the same.

Comment: Which DB are you using ? Please tag it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use something resembling the following pattern.

```
SELECT s1.id "ID",
       s2.time "Scheduled",
       ...
       s6.time "Depart Office",
       datediff(minute, s3.time, s4.time) "Wait Time"
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    id
                    FROM elbat) s1
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,
                              time
                              FROM elbat s2
                              WHERE event = 'Scheduled') s2
                      ON s2.id = s1.id
            ...
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,
                              time
                              FROM elbat
                              WHERE event = 'Depart Office') s6
                      ON s6.id = s1.id;
```

I chose the SQL Server `datediff()` syntax. You may need to rewrite it for your DBMS. If you have a patient table, you should also replace `(SELECT DISTINCT id FROM elbat)` with that patient table. You might also need to come up with a method for multiple appointments for a patient. Include e.g. the day in the joins (or any other attribute with which the different appointments can be distinguished).